# Fire valueChangeListener using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

I have recently been asked to implement a function to control all the `rich:calendar` components based on a single `SessionScoped` `Date` object, that was placed in the header of the `.xhtml` template.

So I solved it with `JQuery`, using something like the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date = $('#mainForm\\:generalDateInputDate').val();

    $('.rf-cal-inp').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).val(date);
            $(this).change();
        }
    });

});
```

And it works just fine, except for a single problem. I thought that invoking `$(this).change();` would fire the `valueChangeListener` associated with some of my calendar components, but it didn't.

In a few of them I really need the `valueChangeListener` to be fired so that things can work correctly.

Is there a way I can do this using `JavaScript/JQuery`?

Here's an example of a `rich:calendar` that needs this behavior:

```
<rich:calendar id="date"
    value="#{managedBean.date}"
    datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" enableManualInput="false"
    valueChangeListener="#{managedBean.dateValueChangeListener}">
    <a4j:ajax onbegin="openLoadingPopup();" oncomplete="closeLoadingPopup();"
        execute="@this" render="date select button" />
</rich:calendar>
```

---

**Additional Info**

- JSF 2.1 with Mojarra Implementation
- Richfaces 4.1 Final
- JBoss 7.1.1 Brontes

Comment: Sure that `disabled` is evaluating as `false` during postback? Because if `true`, it won't be processed at all.

Comment: I tested without the `disabled` attribute. the result was the same. Perhaps I need to do something more to get this event fired. Do you have any guidelines? PS: I'll remove `disabled` from calendar to avoid further confusion

Comment: Okay, then it's caused elsewhere. I can't answer as I can't tell from top of head what HTML `<rich:calendar>` generates.

Comment: I'll Edit and post it here, maybe it'll help.

Comment: Can't post it, it generates too much code. for a single calendar component. I saw no reference of an `onchange` event though. only `onclick`, `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`

Comment: At this point, you don't need to. Just wait for someone with hands on RichFaces experience.

Comment: Oh I see. I just can't find the spot where the calendar triggers the listener. But thanks for trying to help :-)